# PHP - $GET and delete from MySQL

Tags: php

I have an a href which looks like that: `<a href="delete-news.php?deleteID=11">Delete</a>`

And file delete-news.php is as follow:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET["?deleteID='.$id."])) 
{

    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM 'news' WHERE id='$id'");
    echo mysql_error();
    if($result)
        echo "succces";
}
else { echo "GET NOT SET"; }

?>
```

But it is returning `GET NOT SET`. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @wiero - I have changes that but still `GET NOT SET`

Comment: Do **NOT EVER** use a get request to do a delete operation. One webspider on your site and ALL of your data is gone: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this, and for god's sake escape your inputs.

```
if(isset($_GET['deleteID'])) {
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `news` WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['deleteID']). "'");
    echo mysql_error();
    if($result)
        echo "succces";

} else {
    echo 'GET NOT SET';
}
```

Comment: Yes, please escape your inputs.  You are opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks

Comment: Dunhamzzz - what does it mean escape inputes? I'm PHP/MySQL user since Tuesday.

Comment: Google SQL injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection You will need to look into this before coding any more PHP.

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET` will have each element of the GET variables already broken down, so no need to include the URL data. So, in your example, the link `?deleteID=123` would produce `$_GET['deleteID']`.

Try using that, but also remember to sanitize the values you receive in from URLs. If it's going to be a numeric value, I suggest casting it:

```
$deleteID = (int)$_GET['deleteID'];
```

Comment: It's still better to escape as you insert it into the query, what if OP overwrites the value of $id, or copies elsewhere and changes to a non-int variable?

Comment: What if, what if, what if. There will always be exceptions, I can't prevent a [PICNIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error).

Comment: Well you could cater for all those by escaping in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Please also note that changes to the system should only happen via POST, and never GET. Otherwise (for example), you might get a spidering bot that deletes your whole site. See this post for more references:

[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679013/get-vs-post-best-practices`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679013/get-vs-post-best-practices)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET["deleteID"])) 
{
    $id = ($_GET['deleteID']);
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM news WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'");
    echo mysql_error();
    if($result)
        echo "succces";
}
else { echo "GET NOT SET"; }

?>
```

is correct one

Comment: This will return `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''news' WHERE id='11'' at line 1`

Comment: You're not supposed to wrap table names in `'`, use backticks instead (see my response below for more information). :-)

Comment: It's still better to escape as you insert it into the query, what if OP overwrites the value of $id, or copies elsewhere and changes to a non-int variable?

Comment: @genesis that's actually worse

Comment: @Dunhamzzz: 'I have an a href which looks like that: <a href="delete-news.php?deleteID=11">Delete</a>' << op's post. But edited

Comment: that's irrelevant, I'm talking about `mysql_real_escape_strinng()`'ing `$id` as you put it into the query, just incase it's not a number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `$_GET` for just `deleteID`.  Later, reference it as `$_GET['deleteID']`.  Also, call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$_GET['deleteID']` to retrieve your query parameter `$id`.

```
if(isset($_GET["deleteID"])) 
{
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['deleteID']);
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `news` WHERE id='$id'");
    echo mysql_error();
    if($result)
        echo "succces";
}
else { echo "GET NOT SET"; }
```

Comment: this will return `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''news' WHERE id='11'' at line 1`

Comment: @USer yes, single quotes on `news` converted to backquotes. See above

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['deleteID'])) 
    {
        $id = intval($_GET['deleteID']);
        $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `news` WHERE id='$id'");
        echo mysql_error();
        if($result) echo "succces";

    } else { 

        echo "GET NOT SET";

     }
?>
```

Note that I'm making the given `deleteID` into an `int`, meaning that values other than some form of number will become `0`.

Also, you can't wrap a table- and/or column name with `'` - backticks are the way to go!

Comment: It's still better to escape as you insert it into the query, what if OP overwrites the value of `$id`, or copies elsewhere and changes to a non-int variable?

Comment: You may want to ensure that `$id>0` before executing the sql statement.

Comment: Well, yes, that's true. However, I assumed that OP actually knows what he's doing when he's doing it. :) Regarding the `id>0`: there could actually be a row that's got a negative value, but the query itself won't *fail* if no row is found.

Answer (score 0):

You obtain GET NO SET, because the **$_GET** associative array does not contain **?deleteID='.$id**.

In order for you to obtain the id, you need to so something like this:

```
$id = $_GET['deleteID'];
```

Also

```
$result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM 'news' WHERE id='$id'");
```

That is very unsafe as it allows SQL injections. Instead, do:

```
$query = sprintf("DELETE * FROM news WHERE id=%d",
         mysql_real_escape_string($id),
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

I hope this helped.