# Is it possible to Invoke a HttpPost Action method from @Html.ActionLink?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.actionlink

Is it possible to Invoke a HttpPost Action method from `@Html.ActionLink` ?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Delete()
{    
  // delete 
}
```

`@Html.ActionLink("Delete","Delete","Cart")` will render an anchor tag which is a get request.

I have a list of products i am showing in the shopping cart and i want to add a delete button.

Comment: So make delete a get. Why does it need to be a post?

Comment: @mccow002, Generally not a good idea for actions that modify data (such as deleting items) to be GETs. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786070/why-should-you-delete-using-an-http-post-or-delete-rather-than-get

Comment: @mccow002: Get for delete ? Really ? This is something worth to read http://stackoverflow.com/a/679042/40521

Comment: fair enough. Any place I've ever implemented a delete as a get has been behind security, so I didn't have to worry about a google bot or something. But yea, didn't realize all that could happen with the delete as a get on an open site. Try to answer a question, you learn something yourself. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

add a javascript listener on the click event of that actionLink and in the callback function of the listener just do s POST to your action.