# Html, reading data after '?'

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get an HTML/PHP script to interpret data sent after the `?` in a url. I've seen sites that do this, YouTube being one of them. I thought this was called Post Data (not sure if it is), I've been searching for a few days, and I can find is the PHP `$_POST['']` with some HTML forms reading the data from a textbox, but I would like to read directly from the url, EX. www.example.com?ver=1

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: some light reading material: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679013/get-vs-post-best-practices  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: This question should be re-opened.  There is nothing ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical about it.  It most certainly **can** be answered in its current form, as evidenced by the two answers (both of which contain up-votes) below.  If your reason for voting to close is that you think this is obvious, consider for a moment that your attitude towards questions like this is one of the reasons folks have trouble learning.  Sure, a "read the documentation" comment is appropriate, but it isn't a question that should be closed.  It's hard for folks to get started sometimes.

Comment: It's not post data, it's a query string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).  You can find that data in `$_GET`.

```
print_r($_GET);
```

If you need access to the raw data (and you probably don't, unless you need multiples for some variable names), check `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that in HTML pages. In PHP pages, you can read (and process) the parameters using the `$_GET` array. This array contains all the things after which come after ? in the URL. Suppose we have a URL like

```
page.php?a=b&c=d
```

Then we can access `a` and `c` parameters by `$_GET['a']` and `$_GET['b']`. There is also `$_POST` which works a bit different. You can google it to find out more.