# Delete data using get url php string

Tags: php, mysql, string, url, phpmyadmin

I created a page called `delete.php`

with the following code

```
<?php

require_once("database.php");
$con = mysql_connect($config["db_server"],$config["db_user"],$config["db_pass"]);
mysql_select_db($config['db_name'], $con);


// The SQL statement that deletes the record
$strSQL = "DELETE FROM records WHERE record_id = 1";
mysql_query($strSQL);

// Close the database connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Now if I goto `http://www.domain.com/delete.php`
which will will delete record id with 1 in table records.

How do I use php string  so when I go to `http://www.domain.com/delete.php?del?=25`
it deletes `record_id` `25`?

Thanks.

Comment: Apart from apparently having put no effort into finding out what $_GET and $_POST are, you should never do a deletion via a GET request because [GET is for idempotent and safe requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) which a deletion obviously isn't. Besides, you don't want a web spider crawling your deletion.php with various IDs if you want to keep that data.

Answer (score 5):

You would use the [`$_GET` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) to capture the passed variable.

```
$deleteId = $_GET['del'];
$strSQL = "DELETE FROM records WHERE record_id = $deleteId";
```

However, **this is insecure and wrong**. Do not use this code!

You will need to [stop using `mysql_` functions (they are deprecated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?lq=1) and [use prepared statements to help prevent SQL injection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/)

As mentioned in the comments, this method is not suggested due to possible issues with web spiders. [This article](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Spider_of_Doom.aspx) discusses that issue and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/679042/679449) discusses the best practices.

Comment: It's not "not suggested" it's stated "SHOULD NOT".

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your url construction is incorrect. It should be:

```
http://www.domain.com/delete.php?del=25
```

Then you can use `del` via `GET` to access the value:

```
 $del_id = $_GET['del'];
 $strSQL = "DELETE FROM records WHERE record_id = $del_id";
```

[mysql_](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) is deprecated. 
You should be using [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) *or (even better)* [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) *instead.*

The above code is susceptible to whats known as **mysql injection**.

As a rule of thumb, never ever trust the data coming from the user. So what you're doing here is without exaggeration disastrous.

Example:

```
//GET value: dave
query = " SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=$name ";
//Translates to:
query = " SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username='dave' ";


//malicious input
//GET value: 'OR'1
query = " SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=$name ";
//Translates to:
query = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=''OR'1' ";
```

The nasty thing here is, 1 evaluates to true thus returning all usernames and passwords in the users table!

**mysqli_real_escape_string() to the rescue**

Despite being a mouthful to say, this function provides a safeguard by escaping injection attempts with MySQL-friendly '\' quote.

So pumping all your GET/POST data through this function provides a layer of security.

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username'];
```

Now hopefully that makes sense. Despite rhapsodising `mysqli_real_escape_string()` I would highly recommend (at some point) looking into using something a bit more sophisticated like `PDO` instead.

Comment: Also this will be in a admin area, so there is 
require_once("require_login.php");